# How can I save my web access login on the iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

Whenever I try to use the internet on my iPod Touch the Log In screen slides up displaying the log in page for the internet service I'm utilizing (like you'd typically get at hotels, airports, etc). How can I save my login so I don't have to log in every time I wake my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is included by Apple in the latest iOS. You want to list that network as **Auto-Login** in the preferences for that network.

When you are in range, you first have to go to the Wi-Fi Networks sheet in Settings.app, Press the white <kbd>></kbd> with the blue circle and set your preferences for each network:
[image: Wi-Fi Networks]

**Auto-Login** controls whether the log in credentials are saved, so turn that on. You don't need to enable auto-join, but it will reduce the taps to re-join this saved network if the device sleeps or is really out of range.

Turning on Auto-Login makes the device attempt to load www.apple.com and watches as you enter the wifi credentials needed for whatever web site is used to join the wifi network. Many open public sites are automated so don't worry if it sets itself up without prompting you at this point.

[image: auto-join and auto-log in]

Answer (score 0):

[LastPass](http://lastpass.com/help.php?fromwebsite=1&topic=iphone&nw=1&fromwebsite=1) features a built-in browser that will automatically fill your login information for each of your saved LastPass sites.

Comment: This doesn't look like it will work. The log in screen pop-ups automatically for web, e-mail, app store, etc. So I'm assuming it wouldn't be redirected to the LastPass browser. And I'm guessing the screen uses Safari which LastPass doesn't work with. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: LastPass doesn't integrate with the wifi settings. It looks to be what I use 1Password for - storing various web site log in credentials and having a mini browser embedded to automate the entering of that web password. It would be of limited use in storing the password for a web based authentication method for joining wifi but doesn't truly answer your stated question.